# How to plot HAC result as scatter plot (scipy linkage)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scipy

I'm using `scipy` linkage for clustering. I'd like to know what's the easiest way to plot the result into a scatter plot:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage 
from sklearn.manifold import MDS

n = 10
X = [np.random.rand(10) + 1 for i in range(n)]
X = np.concatenate((X, [np.random.rand(10) - 1 for i in range(n)]), 0)

mds = MDS(n_components=2)
X_r = mds.fit(X).embedding_  

# Plot MDS result
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
plt.title("MDS")
plt.scatter(X_r[:,0], X_r[:, 1])

lnk = linkage(X)

# Plot dendogram
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
plt.title("Dendogram")
dendrogram(lnk)

# Plot 'lnk' into scatter plot ..
```

The result

[image]
[image]

What's missing is another colored MDS plot to reflect the cluster assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`fcluster`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster.html) with `lnk` assuming there are two clusters,

```
# Plot 'lnk' into scatter plot ..
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import fcluster
fc = fcluster(lnk, 2, criterion='maxclust')
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
plt.scatter(X_r[:,0],X_r[:,1],c=fc)
```

and then plot a scatter plot with c as the colour. This gives,

[image]

Comment: Hm, but it does not color with the labels assigned by `linkage` :/ Or how can I set the color threshold there?

Comment: Okay got it! Thanks :)